# problems with bindings in listbox with collection

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, binding, listbox

I have a Window with 6 listboxes, i am trying to make a little car database but i have problems with my bindings in the second listbox. When i try to click on a manufacturer in the first listbox the binding doesnt work.

```
<Window x:Class="Autolab.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="700"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="119*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="116*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="137*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="137*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="134*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="134*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="hersteller" Grid.Column="0" DisplayMemberPath="h_name" SelectedValuePath="h_id"/>

    <ListBox x:Name="marke" Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.marken, ElementName=hersteller}" />

    <ListBox x:Name="kraftstoff" Grid.Column="2" />
    <ListBox x:Name="art" Grid.Column="3" />
    <ListBox x:Name="werkstatt" Grid.Column="4" />


</Grid>
```

this is were i have my Collection

```
public partial class herstellers
{
    public herstellers()
    {
        this.marken = new HashSet<marke>();
    }

    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public string h_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<marke> marken { get; set; }
}
```

}

[image: Window]

[image: my Model]

Comment: Can you show your model `marke` that has property `marken`

Comment: Model thats has the property marken?  i dont have it as a property look i posted my Model

Comment: Well, I think it would be much much easier if you do your stuff with `MVVM`. You don't want to tie your `Model` to the `View` in the future.

Comment: Where do you put anything in marken?

Comment: thats the points my information is in the marke table

Comment: If your point is that you don't know how to get information out of the marke table then you do a very poor job of making that point.  "Binding doesn't work" is the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest using `ObservableCollection` rather than `HashSet` with a `ListBox`

```
public partial class herstellers
{
    public herstellers()
    {
        this.marken = new ObservableCollection<marke>();
    }

    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public string h_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<marke> marken { get; set; }
}
```

Next, assuming your `marken` class, you must have at least a property that implements `ICollection` so that the `ItemsSource` on your second list box can get populated.

```
public class Marken
{
  // Assuming this marke is populated.
  public ObservableCollection<int> marke { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but i want to get my information out of my database

Comment: @user3371521 Wrap it inside a `ViewModel`

Comment: what do you exactly mean? i just want to have my bindings from my database by collections

Comment: @user3371521 Check for `MVVM` pattern. Other than that, then make sure that your `marken` is a collection same as `marke`